# Skip changes that already exist

Tags: .net, ado.net

Is there any recommended way to make the `DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable table)` method ignore insertions in the DataTable object that are already inserted into the underlying database (and have same values in all columns)?

Comment: The removal methods are slower than simply allowing the underlying DB to fail on duplicate key values.

Comment: @Strom it doesn't need to fail. It simply needs to skip those rows instead of trying to insert what is already inserted.